# How many endings are there and what is the criteria to achieve them?

Tags: the-talos-principle-2

The first game and its DLC both had multiple endings depending on your in-game choices and how much of a completionist you are.

I'm assuming the sequel has at least two -- one for completing all the golden gate bonus puzzles and one for completing the game without them -- but are there any others? And do any of your other story choices affect the ending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a "joke" ending, that is missable, but can be achieved very quickly and easily by starting a new game. This ending will unlock the **Chicken** achievement.

You will get this ending if you refuse to join the expedition. You can still resume the game after the ending and continue playing normally. There is no need to start a new game.

According to [GameSpot](https://www.gamespot.com/articles/the-talos-principle-2-ending-guide/1100-6519078/), there are 3 "proper" endings:

- Leap of Faith
- Momentum Deferred
- Certain Fathoms in the Earth

You can experience each of the endings in a single playthrough. If you resume the game after the credits, you will be returned to the point just before entering the VTOL. The game will behave as if you never entered the VTOL, allowing you to finish puzzles you may have missed, or find more collectibles. Unfortunately, that also means you will have to redo all the puzzles inside the Megastructure.

Which of the 3 proper endings you'll receive depends only on one final choice at the end of the game.

### Leap of Faith

> Choose to "learn the truth". You will use the machine for the good of humanity.

### Momentum Deferred

> Claim that "humanity is not ready yet". The machine will be shut down for now.

### Certain Fathoms in the Earth

> Choose to "destroy the machine".

---

Each of the endings can be affected by your choices and actions throughout the game:

- Complete all gold puzzles, and do one more task. This appears to affect all endings. The "one more task" is:

> to save Miranda.

- The Mayor of New Jerusalem. This seems to only affect the **Certain Fathoms in the Earth** ending (at least if Byron becomes Mayor).
- Whether Yaqut has chosen to follow you to the end. This appears to affects the **Leap of Faith** and **Certain Fathoms in the Earth** endings if you have completed all gold puzzles (including one more task).
- Whether you found all of Trevor's audio logs (adds an extra scene after the credits). This probably affects all endings (I skipped the credits in 2 of 3 endings, and that scene never appeared when I skipped the credits).

Comment: If you do the "normal" ending without the gold puzzles, can you go back and solve them and do the Leap of Faith ending?

Comment: @Pyritie, yes, you can go back and solve the gold puzzles after reaching an ending. PS: I was too hasty when I wrote my first answer. There are actually 3 endings (4, if you include the Chicken one), and none require completing the gold puzzles. The gold puzzles do affect the endings, though.